# Auto-refresh specific id element using php

Tags: php, http

I have,

```
$url1=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

header("Refresh: 10; URL=$url1");
```

which reloads the page automatically within 10 sec.
Can i put **'#file'** in place of **'REQUEST_URI'** to refresh the div element with `id="file"`?

or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: why not you save your url on session?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using AJAX to make a call to a PHP script which then could be used to update the element. AJAX: [W3 Schools Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp#:%7E:text=AJAX%20allows%20web%20pages%20to,if%20the%20content%20should%20change). [W3 Schools PHP AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

If you have used jQuery or already have it included in your project then that is great simple way to make the queries, [jQuery AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)